# Simple jquery image rollover

Tags: jquery, rollover

I have multiple thumbnails and want the main image to represent a large version of the thumbnail when each thumbnail is rolled over. I appreciate this must be a common usage, but I am struggling to find a simple solution.
I have used the following code, which I appreciate may be poor, but this is all quite new for me.. thanks

```
$('.thumbnail').mouseover(function() {
    var currentimg = $('this').attr('src');
    $('#imageMain img').attr('src', currentimg);
});
```

I haven't included the HTML as I guess it's pretty clear what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried changing

```
$('this').attr('src');
```

with

```
$(this).attr('src');
```

?

Comment: I don't suppose you could point me in the right direction for returning the image back to normal on mouse out?

Comment: So you want it to return to the original state/image?

Comment: What you *could* do is have a variable with the original src in it. And than set the src in the mouseout handler of the main image.

Comment: hmm adding code here doesn't exactly work :) you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class for both rollover states, and then you can just use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function:

```
$(".thumbnail").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("rollover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('this')` to `$(this)`

it should work, when using "this" to refer to the current object, it does not need quotes